# XML - XSLT - Working with auxiliar document and <xsl:next-match>

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

I have the following XML input document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" 
        repName="FirstElementTemp" 
        date="10-05-2001">
    <element1>
        <subElement>
            SomeData
        </subElement>
    </element1>
    <element2>
        <subElement type="2"/>
    </element2>
</report>
```

And I want to add a new element called `<valueIs>` right before the `<element1>` element, with data coming from a second XML input file that I use as a `<xsl:param>`

So basically this is the output I want to get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
        repName="FirstElementTemp"
        date="10-05-2001">
      <valueIs>FIRST DATA</valueIs>
      <element1>
        <subElement>
            SomeData
        </subElement>
      </element1>
      <element2>
            <subElement type="2"/>
      </element2>
</report>
```

This is the XSLT code I'm using (with the second XML document inline, as a ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
  xmlns:jsp="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs jsp"
  expand-text="yes"
  version="3.0">


<xsl:param name="doc2"  xmlns="">
    <secondDoc>
    <elementTemps>
        <elemTemp ID="1" name="FirstElementTemp" />
        <elemTemp ID="2" name="SecondTemplate" />
    </elementTemps>
    <elementReps>
        <elemRep tmpID="1" name="FirstElementRep" >
            <value>FIRST DATA</value>
        </elemRep>
        <elemRep tmpID="2" name="SecondTemplate">
            <value>SECOND DATA</value>
        </elemRep>
    </elementReps>
    </secondDoc>     
  </xsl:param>

<xsl:output indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="cDataElement"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:key name="key1" match="elemTemp" use="@name" xpath-default-namespace=""/>
  <xsl:key name="key2" match="elemRep" use="@tmpID" xpath-default-namespace=""/>

  <xsl:template match="report">
      <xsl:next-match/>
      <xsl:variable name="temp" select="key('key1', @repName, $doc2)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="rep" select="key('key2', $temp/@ID, $doc2)"/>

      <valueIs>
          <xsl:value-of select="$rep/value" xpath-default-namespace=""/>
      </valueIs>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which produces the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
        repName="FirstElementTemp"
        date="10-05-2001">
      <element1>
        <subElement>
            SomeData
        </subElement>
      </element1>
      <element2>
            <subElement type="2"/>
      </element2>
</report>
<valueIs>FIRST DATA</valueIs>
```

I know I can't use the `<xsl:next-match>` there, but the thing is that I need the `<report>` element to be the current node because of the `keys` I'm using,

Is there any way of creating the `<valueIs>` document specifically before the `<element1>` document? I need to keep the `<valueIs>` element inside the `<report>` element because this element is the root node...

Thank you!

Alexandre Jacinto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of relying on `<xsl:next-match>` to perform all of the work, put some of the [identity-template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) logic into your template to copy the element, apply-templates to it's attributes, insert your custom content, and then apply-templates to the child nodes:

```
<xsl:template match="report">
    <xsl:variable name="temp" select="key('key1', @repName, $doc2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="rep" select="key('key2', $temp/@ID, $doc2)"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <valueIs>
            <xsl:value-of select="$rep/value" xpath-default-namespace=""/>
        </valueIs>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Alternatively, you could change the template to match on the first child element: `report/*[1]` and then adjust the XPath when selecting from `key1` to jump up to the `report` element to select it's `@repName`, generate the new element and then use `xsl:next-match`.

```
<xsl:template match="report/*[1]">
    <xsl:variable name="temp" select="key('key1', ../@repName, $doc2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="rep" select="key('key2', $temp/@ID, $doc2)"/>
    <valueIs>
        <xsl:value-of select="$rep/value" xpath-default-namespace=""/>
    </valueIs>
    <xsl:next-match/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you, both of your answers work, but also both of them create a xmlns attribute inside the <valueIs> element like this: <valueIs xmlns=" ">FIRST DATA<valueIs>. Do you know how I can avoid this?

Comment: The reason for the extra `xmlns=""` is because your input XML elements are bound to the Jasper namespace and do not use a namespace-prefix and your `valueIs` element is not bound to any namespace. There are several ways to adjust to ensure that your `valueIs` element is in the Jasper namespace: Use the `jsp` prefix in the template `<jsp:valueIs>`, declare the default namespace for your stylesheet to be the Jasper namespace `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"`, put the namespace inline `<valueIs xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports">`

Comment: Thank you for the so well exlplained answer!